# Verifying purchase receipts in both iOS 6 and 7

Tags: ios6, ios7, in-app-purchase

I am verifying in-app-purchase receipts using the following code:

```
- (void) completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction*) transaction
{   
    NSData* receipt = nil;

    // 1. Attempt <app receipt> first (iOS 7.x)

    NSBundle* mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];

    if ([mainBundle respondsToSelector:@selector(appStoreReceiptURL)]) {

        NSURL* appStoreReceiptURL = [mainBundle appStoreReceiptURL]; // <- CRASH

        receipt = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:appStoreReceiptURL];
    }

    // 2. Fallback to <transaction receipt> (iOS < 7.0)
    if (!receipt) {    
        receipt = [transaction transactionReceipt];
    }

    // 3. Have server verify it with iTunes:    
    [self verifyReceipt:receipt forTransaction:transaction];
}
```

On an iOS 6 device, the execution stops at the line `NSURL* appStoreReceiptURL = [mainBundle appStoreReceiptURL];` and the console spits:

`-[NSBundle appStoreReceiptURL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x208492d0`

Am I missing something? Wasn't `-respondsToSelector:` supposed to take care of this? Must I fall back to checking the OS version directly??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

YES you should check version number directly in case of this appStoreReceiptURL Method. 
**appStoreReceiptURL**

In iOS, use the following code to detect whether this method is available:

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
   // Load resources for iOS 6.1 or earlier
} else {
   // Load resources for iOS 7 or later
}
```

**Note: The general best practice of weak linking using the respondsToSelector: method cannot be used here. Prior to iOS 7, the method (appStoreReceiptURL) was implemented as private API, but that implementation called the doesNotRecognizeSelector: method.**

**Reference:NSBundle Class reference**